# Unable to disasembly my app -- no debugging information found

Tags: linux, assembly, fasm

I'm trying to disassembly app written in assembly. I'm on Linux, x64:

```
$ objdump -d my_app 

my_app:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

That's it. What's wrong with it? It's not a simple `hello world` of  a few lines, it's around 200 lines of code.

The same with gbd:

```
$ gdb -q my_app 
Reading symbols from my_app...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb)
```

And

```
$ radare2 my_app 
Warning: Cannot initialize section headers
Warning: Cannot initialize strings table
Warning: Cannot initialize dynamic strings
Warning: Cannot initialize dynamic section
 -- Calculate checksums for the current block with the commands starting with '#' (#md5, #crc32, #all, ..)
```

**update**:

```
$ objdump -D my_app 

my_app:     file format elf64-x86-64
```

compiling:

```
   $ fasm my_app.asm 
   # => my_app
```

**update2:**

```
; simplified

format ELF64 executable 3

include "import64.inc"
interpreter "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2"
needed "libc.so.6"
import printf, close

segment readable
    A equ 123
    B equ 222
    C equ 333

segment readable writeable
    struc s1 a, b, c {
      .a1 dw a
      .b1 dw b
      .c dd c
    }

    msg:
        .m1 db "aaa", 0
        .m2 db "bbb", 0
        .m3 db "ccc", 0

segment readable executable
entry $
    mov rax, 2
    mov rdi, "something.txt"
    mov rsi, 0
    syscall

    ; .............
    ; omitted
```

Comment: Did you try `objdump -D` to disassemble all sections?  Or even `ndisasm` to disassemble the whole file as if it were a flat binary.  (Default mode is 16-bit, so set it to 64-bit).

Comment: Have you tried with a simple fasm program and built it the same way to see what happens?

Comment: @MichaelPetch the same thing

Comment: @PeterCordes ndisasm worked but still provided pretty complicated disasm code, way more complicated than I have in my app. Is there other way?

Comment: `ndisasm` is disassembling the ELF headers as instructions; it doesn't know about object files so it assumes everything is a flat binary.  If `objdump -D` doesn't work, are you sure your app even has any machine code in its segments?  Try `gdb ./my_app`, and `b *0`.  You'll have to delete that breakpoint right away (because `*0` isn't a valid address), but it will stop before the first instruction of your program executes, wherever that is, so you can find the entry point.  You don't need debug symbols to use gdb; it has a disassembly mode.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: I'd say there is something wrong with your assembly file and it is generating an unusual ELF file (ones that don't seem to have sections?). Would you humour us and post all 200 lines? Or reduce the assembly file to a minimal set of ins that still reproduces the same behavior once assembled into an executable

Comment: @jww he's using fasm so there might not even be a link stage (fasm will usually allow you to go from assembly code to executable with one command)

Comment: @MichaelPetch, correct

Comment: @Uji without seeing all your code or a minimal complete example that produces the same problem it is hard to tell.You could email it (your entire ASM file) to me at mpetch@gmail.com and I could take a look and may be able to complete a minimal example from it that would make this question answerable.I believe the issue lies in your actual assembly file which you just aren't showing.

Comment: My main concern is that objdump with `-D` gives you one line of info `my_app:     file format elf64-x86-64`. I would expect it to dump instructions from the .text segments but it isn't. It actually acts like there is some sort of problem with the sections.

Comment: @Uji,  Could you share the source code my_app?  let me take a try to see if we have the same result.

Comment: @MichaelPetch updated

Comment: @PeterCordes updated

Comment: `readelf` says: _Number of section headers: 0_ It also tells you where the entry point is, and knowing that, `gdb` can debug it if you place a breakpoint there.

Comment: I recommend you do not create executable directly, instead use a linker.

Comment: @Jester I recommend you first try fasm yourself and then give advice.

Comment: Guess what, I have tried it. Why is everybody so rude these days?

Comment: @Jester then everyone, including its creator, do it wrong -- they don't use a linker.

Comment: @Jester why everybody is so sensitive these days so that they see rudeness everywhere? go claim your mummy

Comment: You can use fasm without a linker, I didnt't say otherwise. But using one will give you better output, you even get sections you can name. Do whatever you want but then don't come whining...

Comment: @Jester, yes, but using a linker must bring an overhead, must it not? namely, an output file will be a bit bigger and slower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking `fasm` to directly produce an ELF binary without the use of a linker will only create segments but no sections in the output. This confuses some tools. In particular `objdump -d` is specifically documented to operate on sections. Note that `gdb` can still debug and disassemble it, if you give it some addresses, e.g. the entry point.

Comment: > Note that gdb can still debug and disassemble it, if you give it some addresses, e.g. the entry point.

Comment: @Uji you can abuse the "break on any failure" mechanism of `gdb`. Use `file` to load it, then put breakpoint on invalid address like zero `b *0`, then `run` ... the `gdb` will break on first instruction because of invalid breakpoint. Delete it `d 1` (if "breakpoint 1" was added), and since here you can `stepi`/etc...

Comment: @Uji and Ped7g: you can also `readelf -a` and look at the "entry point" address.  (The `b *0` trick is really handy, though, and also works for PIEs with ASLR.)

Comment: @PeterCordes readefl says "  Entry point address:               0x40394a", what to do with that?

Comment: @Uji: `gdb ./my_app`  / `b *0x40394a` to set a breakpoint there.

Comment: @PeterCordes it still sort of amazes me there's no simple way to do that from gdb directly, and some other tool must be used. Then again, the gdb is kind of shell-like tool, like old ftp, so there's maybe way to run external command from inside? I don't care, using `b *0` is for me perfect, I will not forget that so easily as anything else (`readelf` is completely off limits to my memory).

Comment: @Ped7g: There might be a way from within gdb, but I don't know it.  It's designed primarily as a source-level debugger, not a binary-analysis tool.

Comment: At least some versions of `gdb` print the entry point if you do `info file`. Unfortunately that only works once the program has been started too.